# three.js how to render a texture mapped OBJ file in WebGL?

Tags: three.js, webgl, texture-mapping, .obj

## three.js: how to render a *texture mapped* OBJ file in WebGL?

I'm a newbie to **Three.JS** and **WebGL**.  I have a 3D scanner that makes texture mapped OBJ files and *I want to create a simple WebGL viewer that allows the user to view the 3D model from any direction.*

I did a web search to find examples for how to do this, and  I followed the instructions from ***Porting 3D graphics to the web — WebGL intro part 2*** (*http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/porting-3d-graphics-to-the-web-webgl-intro-part-2/*) by **Luz Caballero (@gerbile)** to create a page to do this.  The instructions were well written, but only after following some suggestions by **Darryl_Lehman** on another StackOverflow page to add a *materials* object to the *loader* and *CreateScene* function calls, was I eventually able to get the code to render my model at all.  Unfortunately the revised code is now rendering my model all **monochrome**, unlike the example by Luz Caballero which included the texture map.

Thanks to some other suggestions from **@WestLangley** and **@mrdoob**, I was finally able to get the texture mapping working.

That fixes my problem.   I'm including code that is working for me in case anyone else needs an example:

### The WORKING code:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>SoundFit 3D Model Viewer</h2>
        <!-- p>by Scott L. McGregor, SoundFit</p -->
        <!-- p>adapted from the <a href="https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js">Three.js</a> example webgl_objconvert_test.html</p -->
        <!-- p>and based on <a href="http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/porting-3d-graphics-to-the-web-webgl-intro-part-2/"> 
        Porting 3D graphics to the web — WebGL intro part 2</a> by 
        <href="http://dev.opera.com/author/dropoutwannabe">Luz Caballero.</a>
        With additional help from WestLangley and Darrel_Lehman on StackOverflow.
        </p --> 
</div>

<script src="three.js-master/build/three.js"></script>
    <script src="three.js-master/examples/js/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/RequestAnimationFrame.js"></script>
    <script>
        if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

        var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
        var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
        var FLOOR = 0;

        var container;

        var camera, scene;
        var webglRenderer;

        var zmesh, geometry;

        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
        init();

        function init() {
            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            // camera
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 100000 );
            camera.position.z = 25;
            camera.position.y = 15;
            camera.position.x = 0;  

            // scene
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            // lights
            var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x777777 ); // median lighting levels
            scene.add( ambient );

            // more lights
            var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
            directionalLight.position.set( 0, -70, 100 ).normalize();
            scene.add( directionalLight );
        }

        // renderer
        webglRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        webglRenderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
        webglRenderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";
        container.appendChild( webglRenderer.domElement );

        // loader
        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(),
        callbackModel = function(geometry, materials) { createScene( geometry, materials, 90, FLOOR, -50, 105 ) };

        loader.load( "obj/mesh.js", callbackModel );
        function createScene( geometry, materials, x, y, z, b ) {
            zmesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );

            zmesh.material.materials[ 0 ].side = THREE.DoubleSide; 
            zmesh.material.materials[ 1 ].side = THREE.DoubleSide; 
            zmesh.rotation.set( - Math.PI / 2, 0, 0 ); 

            zmesh.position.set( 0, 16, 0 );
            zmesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
            scene.add( zmesh );
        }

        animate();  

        function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
            mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
            mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY );
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
        }

        function render() {
            zmesh.rotation.set(-mouseY/500 + 1, -mouseX/200, 0);
            webglRenderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
    </script>

</body>
```